# ora-1658: unable to creat initial extent for segment in tablespace

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe

i'm getting the error "ora-1658: unable to create initial extent for segment in tablespace MYTBS" when trying to import a dump using imp command.i'm using oracle XE 11.2 in a standalone windows machine. database backup is around 200MB. following is my table space setup.[image]

how can i correct this error? schema that i'm trying to import has tables defined for tables space MYTBS.

Comment: (1) this relates to database administration so is off-topic for Stack Overflow, (2) it looks as if your tablespace has no datafiles in it.

Comment: i could resolve the issue by command -alter database datafile '<path to datfile>\MYTBS.DBF' autoextend on;

Answer (score 10):

The error should

> ora-01658 unable to create initial extent for segment in tablespace  ????

to solve the problem:

You will need an account with DBA privileges to do one of two things , and [link](https://community.oracle.com/message/10499995)

1. extend the datafile to add space (ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE  RESIZE ) , or autoextend (ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE  autoextend on)
   [Changing Datafile Size](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dfiles003.htm#ADMIN11423)
2. add a new datafile to the tablespace (ALTER TABLESPACE  ADD DATAFILE 
   [ALTER TABLESPACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3002.htm#SQLRF01002)

And if your datafile has been reached `32GB` , please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350703/ora-01652-unable-to-extend-temp-segment-by-128-in-tablespace-system-how-to-ext).

Comment: The provided urls don't work for me, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dfiles003.htm#ADMIN11423 for details.

Answer (score 0):

**Get Tablespace Details:**

```
SELECT * FROM dba_tablespaces;
```

**Get Datafile location for respective user:**

```
SELECT * FROM dba_data_files;
```

**Add another Datafile to the user, increasing the overall space:**
**Code:**

```
ALTER TABLESPACE <tablespace_name> 
ADD DATAFILE <'new_datafile_location'>
SIZE <Size>;
```

**Example:**

```
ALTER TABLESPACE USERS 
ADD DATAFILE '/home/oracle/oracle_home/ora19c/oradata/ARESDB/users03.dbf' 
SIZE 3000M;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with the following command

```
alter database datafile '/somepath/somename.dbf' autoextend on maxsize unlimited;
```